# Fiz uma aplicação/jogo em java e utilizei MVC. Porém já conclui e não coloquei nada no Model, é correto?

Tags: java, mvc, aplicação-desktop

Fiz uma aplicação/jogo em java e utilizei **MVC**. Porém já conclui a aplicação e não coloquei nada no Model. Fiz tudo no Controller e View. Minha aplicação não pede nenhum dado de usuário e nem informa pontuação, desempenho de usuário.

Então não vi a necessidade de tem um Model. Vocês acham estranho uma aplicação não ter a parte de Model?

No meu jogo, tem uma parte de tempo (se chegar ate 10 segundos acabe o jogo), essa parte relacionada a contar os segundos, e relacionada a thread, eu deixei no controller, mas agora não sei se fiz certo.

Veja, eu tenho isso no meu controller:

```
public class ContarTempo extends Thread{
        public void run() {
            while(!fim){
                try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (Exception e) {}
                segundos++;
                tfo.getLblTempo().setText(segundos + "");

                contsecundario = segundos + 0;


                if(contsecundario == 10 && verificarCaso.equals("b") ){
                    tfo.desaparecerFase1();
                    tfo.getBtJogarNovamente().setVisible(true);
                    tfo.getBtVoltarTutorial().setVisible(true);
                    tfo.getLblNomeOu().setVisible(true);
                    segundos = 0;
                    obj.suspend();
                }

                else if(contsecundario == 10 && verificarCaso.equals("c") ){
                    tfo.desaparecerFase1_1();
                    tfo.getBtJogarNovamente_1().setVisible(true);
                    tfo.getBtVoltarTutorial().setVisible(true);
                    tfo.getLblNomeOu().setVisible(true);
                    segundos = 0;
                    obj.suspend();
                }

                else if(contsecundario == 10 && verificarCaso.equals("d") ){
                    tfo.desaparecerFase1_2();
                    tfo.getBtJogarNovamente_2().setVisible(true);
                    tfo.getBtVoltarTutorial().setVisible(true);
                    tfo.getLblNomeOu().setVisible(true);
                    segundos = 0;
                    obj.suspend();
                }

                else if(contsecundario == 10 && verificarCaso.equals("e") ){
                    tfo.desaparecerFase1_3();
                    tfo.getBtJogarNovamente_3().setVisible(true);
                    tfo.getBtVoltarTutorial().setVisible(true);
                    tfo.getLblNomeOu().setVisible(true);
                    segundos = 0;
                    obj.suspend();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Difícil dizer sem conhecer todo o contexto, mas provavelmente fez errado, parece que não precisava de MVC. Muitos casos não precisam, mas as pessoas usam mesmo assim.

Comment: mas o que eu poderia colocar no Model? è um joguinho de acertar os pares de cartas iguais, desses bem comuns, o que deveria ir no Model?

Comment: Se não tem o que colocar, não coloque nada. Se não precisa de um model, provavelmente não precisa de um MVC.

Comment: Entendi. sem model, sem MVC! isto?

Comment: Não necessariamente, mas se é algo simples, pra que usar uma arquitetura complicada?

Comment: nesse caso nem foi complicado... tudo de botões e afins no View e tratei os eventos no Controller... mas não achei o que colocar no Model, vc acha que sem interação do usuário, pode ser que ainda assim eu não tenha colocado o que deveria no Model?

Comment: Esse código que você postou é muito pouco para se determinar se você precisava ou não de Model.

Comment: coloquei um pouco mais!

Comment: Editei minha resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O *Model* é a parte do MVC que especifica quais são as regras da sua aplicação. Não sei que tipo de jogo você está fazendo, mas em um jogo típico, seria no *Model* que você colocaria coisas como jogadores, pontuação, mapeamento de áreas dominadas por cada jogador, tabuleiro, inimigos, espaçonaves, submarinos, números de dados, cartas de baralho ou seja lá o que for que haja no seu jogo. Se o *Model* ficou vazio e tudo está no *View* e no *Controller*, então você não usou MVC de verdade.

Em uma aplicação MVC corretamente implementada, o *View* é intercambiável sem alteração do *Model*. Por exemplo, vamos supor que o seu jogo tenha uma versão para Android, uma para Swing e uma com um frontend com Ajax + HTML5 e uma usando apenas linha de comando com `System.out.println`. Todas essas tecnologias têm camadas *View* bem diferentes, mas se o seu projeto foi feito corretamente como prega o MVC, então essas duas afirmações deveriam ser verdadeiras:

- O *Model* não sofre qualquer alteração quando ocorre uma troca da tecnologia do *View*.
- Todas as regras que governam o jogo e modelam os conceitos a ele pertencentes estão dentro do *Model*.

Se uma das duas afirmações acima for falsa, então você não seguiu o padrão MVC, ao menos não corretamente. No seu caso, tenho certeza que ambas as afirmações são falsas em sua totalidade, e portanto a sua arquitetura não é MVC e você deve ter acoplado conceitos e regras do jogo a conceitos da *View*.

Um exemplo simples de violação do MVC é esse:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Jogador {
    // ...
}
```

A simples presença do `import` ali já é uma violação grave do MVC, pois o `Jogador` é algo que deveria estar no *Model* enquanto que `JOptionPane` é algo que é inerente a *View*. Outras violações seriam essas:

```
public class Tabuleiro {
    private JPanel[] casas;

    // ...
}
```

```
public class Jogador {

   // ...

   public void gameOver() {
       System.out.println("Infelizmente o nosso herói se foi sem concluir a sua missão."
               + " Uma pena. GAME OVER!");
   }
}
```

```
public class MonstroInimigo {

    private int hp;

    // ...

    public void colocarDadosNaRequisicao(HttpServletRequest rq) {
        rq.setAttribute("mostroHP", hp);
    }
}
```

```
public class MesaDePoker extends Activity {
    private List<Carta> baralho;
    private List<Jogador> jogadores;

    // ...
}
```

Observe que em todos esses casos, ao colocar `JButton` dentro do *Model*, o mesmo fica preso a usar uma *View* baseada em Swing. Ao colocar `System.out.println`, ele fica preso a usar uma *View* baseada em console. Ao usar `HttpServletRequest`, ele fica preso a usar uma *Controller* e uma *View* baseada em Servlets. Ao usar *Activity*, ele fica preso a usar uma *Controller* e uma *View* baseada em Android. Em todas elas, perde-se a característica de ter-se uma *View* intercambiável e com isso perde-se o MVC. Além disso, `Jogador`, `Tabuleiro`, `MonstroInimigo` e `MesaDePoker` são coisas que modelam o funcionamento e as regras do jogo, e portanto deveriam estar no *Model*, caso contrário, novamente haverá uma violação do MVC.

**EDITADO**:

Embora o seu código esteja incompleto e use diversas variáveis que você não definiu no código que você apresengtou, o que você apresenta claramente viola o modelo MVC. A modelagem das fases do seu jogo deveria estar dentro do seu *Model*, enquanto que coisas como botões deveriam estar na *View*. O fato do objeto `tfo`, seja ele o que for, ter métodos `desaparecerFase1` e `getBtVoltarTutorial` evidencia que conceitos do *Model* foram misturados a conceitos da *View* em uma mesma classe.

Quando você for criar o seu projeto, você deve criar um conjunto de classes que modele suas regras de negócio sem utilizar qualquer conceito referente a interface gráfica, o que seria o *Model*. Conceitos como cliques, toques de tela e etc também estão fora do *Model*.

Depois, para fazer a interface gráfica é que o *View* surge, responsável apenas por renderizar na tela (ou em qualquer coisa semelhante). Na *View* é que você coloca labels, botões, menus e etc. No entanto, você não adiciona os comportamentos desses menus, labels e botões na *View*. Esse comportamento fica no *Controller*, que também é ressponsável por traduzir o *Model* para a *View* e vice-versa.

Aliás, o fato de haver métodos `tfo.desaparecerFase1();`, `tfo.desaparecerFase1_1()`, `tfo.desaparecerFase1_2()`, etc, já é um indício forte de uma má modelagem e de uma inadequada orientação a objetos. O certo, a meu ver, seria você ter um objeto de uma classe `Fase` (no seu *Model*) e nele ter métodos `aparecer()` e `desaparecer()`. Esses métodos do *Model* seriam então usados pelo *Controller*, que poderia manter uma variável de instância do tipo `Fase`. Semelhaantemente, a *View* também deve ter problemas análogos tal como evidenciado pela presença de métodos `getBtJogarNovamente()`, `getBtJogarNovamente_1()` e `getBtJogarNovamente_2()`. Ele deveria saber em que fase ele está ao consultar o *Model*, sem que a *View* ou o *Controller* tivesse que ter métodos específicos para diferentes fases do jogo.

Quanto a esse comentário:

> Esse tfo.desaparecerFase1() é o seguinte: ele da um setVisibleTrue nos componentes da view (estão setados na view como false, quando o controle ativa, ele fica como true). por isso que eu achei que tinha que ficar dentro da view, o controle só ativa esses componentes. Mas o model eu realmente não entendo, já li, reli sobre o assunto, mas ainda não consigo aplicar ao meu projeto

O que ocorre é que você parece ter os componentes das views de todas as fases simultaneamente. Ou seja, ao invés de carregar uma fase e criar os elementos da view dela e quando esta terminar destruí-los, você está carregando todas as fases e colocando todos os elementos de todas as fases na tela e dando `setVisible(true)` e `setVisible(false)` neles.

Se você tiver um objeto `Fase` dentro do seu *Model*, esse tipo de coisa naturalmente vai acabar parando em um outro lugar que nem a *View* e *Controller* saberá criar a *View* ao olhar para a `Fase` no *Model* seja ela qual for.

Comment: Esse tfo.desaparecerFase1() é o seguinte: ele da um setVisibleTrue nos componentes da view (estão setados na view como false, quando o controle ativa, ele fica como true). por isso que eu achei que tinha que ficar dentro da view, o controle só ativa esses componentes. Mas o model eu realmente não entendo, já li, reli sobre o assunto, mas ainda não consigo aplicar ao meu projeto

Comment: pode da uma olhada no meu último comentário?

Comment: @Gabriella. Ok, mas vou demorar uns minutos para relembrar de tudo.

Comment: @Gabriella Editei a resposta. Mas confesso que é difícil falar-se muita coisa sem ser genérico demais porque para me aprofundar seria necessário ver o seu código completo, e isso já seria algo para alguma outra pergunta.

Comment: mas se eu crio um objeto fase dentro do model, no meu caso, tudo de interface estaria dentro de fase, por isso que eu não entendo... uma hora tem que separar tudo q for de inteface na view, outro momento tem que colocar no model! vc executou o projeto que mandei?: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268646/dúvida-sobre-mvc-no-meu-projeto?noredirect=1#comment550422_268646